# Изменять путь к файлу базы данных

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

Изучаю работу в `WPF` с `SQLite` через `Entity Framework`. Все подключается и работает, но адрес файла базы данных указывается жестко в `App.config`, а нужно сделать так, чтобы в программе можно было выбрать нужный файл. `DbContext` принимает `nameOrConnectionString`, имя ИЛИ строку подключения. Имя понятно, оно-то и указывается в `App.config`. А вот в каком виде можно передать строку подключения? Или поправьте меня, если я неправильно размышляю.

Comment: Сделайте свойство в классе `DbContext`, дальше задавайте ему что надо, например `DbPath = Path.Join(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "MySuperDB.db");`, ну а подключение будет таким: `protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) => options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbPath}");`. Вот простой пример того, как задать путь через код, без всяких `App.config`, дальше уже развивайте это как вам надо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если честно, не совсем понимаю, как это сделать, если класс DbContext наследуется и входит в состав подключаемой библиотеки

Comment: Вот в этом классе, который унаследовал и делайте все это.